# Rails: Why is my session not being destroyed (even after I restart my comp!)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My sessions were working fine and dandy and then I

1. created a "remember me?" checkbox for the login
2. tried adding a mailer for registration
3. created a new user to see if my mailer was working

and now when I try to logout it won't let me log out even after I restart my computer! How I know this is that my nav bar has a condition for being signed in so you see the login link if you're not logged in. I've even tried deleting the cookie but it keeps reappearing everytime I refresh the page.

users#create

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
      sign_in(@user)
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

navbar

```
    <nav class="clearfix">
        <% if !signed_in? %>
            <%= link_to "home", root_url %>
        <% else %>
            <%= link_to "my profile", current_user %>
            <%= link_to "edit profile", edit_user_path(current_user) %>
            <%= link_to "friends", user_friends_path(current_user) %>
        <% end %>

        <div class="rightnav">
        <% if signed_in? %>
            <%= link_to "active users", users_path %>
            <%= link_to "log out", signout_path, method: "delete", :id =>"logoutlink" %>
        <% else %>
            <%= link_to "sign up", new_user_path, :id => "signuplink" %>
            <!-- <a href="#" id="signuplink">Sign Up</a> -->
            <%= link_to "log in", signin_path, :id => "loginlink" %>
            <!-- <a href="#" id="loginlink">Log In</a> -->
        <% end %>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

sessions controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && (!params[:session][:email].blank?) && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    # if params[:remember_me]
    #   cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    # else
    #   cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    # end
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user_path(user)
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email and/or password."
      render 'new'
    end
end

def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
end
```

end

sessions helper

```
module SessionsHelper

def sign_in(user)
    self.current_user = user
end

def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
end

def sign_out
  self.current_user = nil
  cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end

def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
end

def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end
```

end

let me know if you need any other files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out. I just changed

`cookies.delete(:remember_token)`

to

`cookies[:remember_token] = nil`